# Hydrodynamic interactions and finite-size corrections

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, statistical-mechanics, computational-physics

In molecular dynamics simulations of fluids it is known that diffusion coefficient $D$ of fluid simulated under periodic boundary conditions in a cubic box with size $L$ decays with a factor $\frac{1}{L}$ as the box is made smaller. In the works from Yeh, Hummer and Dünweg it was concluded that these finite-size effect are caused by the existence of a Oseen flow around the fluid particles, and the finite-size effects are therefore effectively hydrodynamic interactions between the fluid particles and their periodic images. In this question I would like to understand these insight in more detail.

**Oseen tensor**

A point force $f(\vec r ) = f_{0}\delta (\vec r)$ applied at the origin $\vec r = \vec 0$ on an unbounded incompressible fluid with viscosity $\eta$ results in a stationary velocity profile peaked at the origin and decaying as $\vec v \sim\frac{1}{r}$ to zero at infinity $r \rightarrow \infty$. More precisely the stationary solution of the Navier-Stokes equation is $\vec v(\vec r) = \frac{f_{0}}{8\pi\eta r}(I + \frac{\hat{r}\hat{r}}{r^{2}} )$, this is called Oseen tensor. This field can be plotted in two dimension to give the plot below (figure 1).

**Finite-size effects**

The authors derive the equivalent of the above Oseen tensor for a fluid bounded within a finite size $L$. Roughly, this is done by writing the above equation of Oseen tensor in terms of Fourier modes and then computing the Fourier sum with exclusion of modes not allowed because of the finite size of the box. Then they show that the difference between the bounded and unbounded case is $\sim\frac{1}{L}$. The flow field of Oseen tensor with finite size is plotted (figure 2).

**Questions**

Although I can follow the derivation of this "finite-size correction", I can still not clearly and intuitively explain this correction based on the flow fields shown below. In other words, intuitively it makes sense that due to a "effective repulsion" between a particle and its periodic image a decrease of diffusivity may result, but

- How is this encoded in the flow fields of the Oseen tensor (bounded and unbounded case) ?
- How can we intuitively construct the flow field in figure 2 based on the flow field in figure 1. In principle figure 2 results from a sort of reflection with the boundaries, but this is not very clear from the plot.

I could more details of the plots if required.

**Figure 1**

[image]

**Figure 2**

[image]